# Cannot build LLVM and Clang

Tags: llvm, clang

I have tried to compile *clang* and *llvm* using the [clang getting started manual](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html). However, at step 5, when I do *make*, I get the following error. Any idea what is going on here, and how to fix it? Note that I am using Ubuntu 10.04 on a 64 bit x86 system.

```
cp: cannot stat `/home/MetallicPriest/Desktop/build/tools/clang/runtime/compiler-rt/clang_linux/full-x86_64/libcompiler_rt.a': No such file or directory
make[4]: *** [/home/MetallicPriest/Desktop/build/Debug+Asserts/lib/clang/3.1/lib/linux/libclang_rt.full-x86_64.a] Error 1
rm /home/MetallicPriest/Desktop/build/Debug+Asserts/lib/clang/3.1/lib/linux/.dir
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/MetallicPriest/Desktop/build/tools/clang/runtime/compiler-rt'
make[3]: *** [compiler-rt/.makeall] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/MetallicPriest/Desktop/build/tools/clang/runtime'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/MetallicPriest/Desktop/build/tools/clang'
make[1]: *** [clang/.makeall] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/MetallicPriest/Desktop/build/tools'
make: *** [all] Error 1
## Heading ##
```

Comment: Sounds like you forgot the compiler-rt step?

Comment: No, I did it, I have compiler-rt in my llvm/projects directory.

Comment: Just to help triage the problem, could you try to download & build a released version (such as 3.0)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instruction given on [this site](http://solarianprogrammer.com/2011/10/16/llvm-clang-libc-linux/) work!

Comment: The "clang getting started" instructions worked fine for me, multiple times on multiple machines and Ubuntu versions, without ever building libc++. So I wonder what's different in your case

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. As Eli suggested, I got the 3.0 release. It doesn't come with a 'getting started' but you can follow the INSTALL file from clang's root top.

You should be able to copy/paste the following (as root of course for the /usr/local/ part)

```
export NUMCPU=4 # or however many cores you want to paralell build with
export ORIGDIR=$PWD
wget http://llvm.org/releases/3.0/llvm-3.0.tar.gz
tar -zxf llvm-3.0.tar.gz
cd llvm-3.0.src/tools
wget http://llvm.org/releases/3.0/clang-3.0.tar.gz
tar -zxf clang-3.0.tar.gz
mv clang-3.0.src clang
cd $ORIGDIR
mkdir build
cd build
../llvm-3.0.src/configure --prefix=/usr/local
make -j$NUMCPU
cd tools/clang
make install
```

--

update, I should also note that following the 'getting started guide' with latest subversion (2012 09 10) actually does work , and i copy/pasted the lines exactly from the 'getting started' page http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html (including 'optional' stuff) on a Fedora machine on ppc64.