# Problems while trying to build LLVM and Clang

Tags: build, compiler-errors, llvm, clang

I tried to build LLVM and Clang but am getting this error :

> cp: cp: cp: cannot stat `/home/saurabh/Build/clang-build/build/tools/clang/runtime/compiler-rt/clang_linux/asan-i386/libcompiler_rt.a'cannot stat`/home/saurabh/Build/clang-build/build/tools/clang/runtime/compiler-rt/clang_linux/ubsan-x86_64/libcompiler_rt.a'cannot stat `/home/saurabh/Build/clang-build/build/tools/clang/runtime/compiler-rt/clang_linux/ubsan-i386/libcompiler_rt.a': No such file or directory
>   : No such file or directory: No such file or directory

I went through [Cannot build LLVM and Clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177633/cannot-build-llvm-and-clang) but it doesn't seem to have any reasons why he had gotten a similar error (hence I am asking it again). I have tried to remove the -Werror flags in compiler-rt/make/ relevant files, since before that, it was stopping on this error :

> /home/saurabh/Build/clang-build/llvm/projects/compiler-rt/lib/tsan/rtl/tsan_mutex.cc:53:13: error: 
>         comparison of constant 4294967295 with expression of type 'int' is always
>         false [-Werror,-Wtautological-constant-out-of-range-compare]
>         if (z == MutexTypeLeaf) {
>             ~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   1 error generated.

I had asked on #llvm and had been suggested that. Any ideas what could be causing this ?
Fwiw, I am on Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit.

Comment: Saurabh - Instead of editing your question with the solution, you should post an answer and mark it as accepted (or mark one of the other answers as accepted).

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html#getting-started-quickly-a-summary. Be aware of the software dependencies you have to install. Also, check again if your --prefix=directory is set. If you cannot install Clang over LLVM (after you succeded to install LLVM), you can try install it using apt-get install clang and clang++. Therefore, you can compile your LLVM passes using this clang. For other corresponding packages, like VMkit for Java, you have to install ant and oracle jdk.

Answer (score 0):

My LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable wasn't set properly.  After I corrected it, this problem went away.